# str.replace() deletes column in python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
id          data


135790075   job done, pay by card 4444-5555-6666-7777
```

I have 25k such rows where id is unique. Next I pass each card number to Luhn check and mask the card numbers that passed the check.

```
data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
summ = data['summary']
creditcards = []
regex_match_index_list =[]
Validcardsfound = 0
regex_count = 0
for i in range(2):
    temp = re.findall(r'(\d\B(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b)',str(values[i]))

    if temp:
        for each in temp:

            regex_count = regex_count + 1
            if doLuhn(str(each)) is True:


                creditcards.append(each)
                Validcardsfound = Validcardsfound + 1
                regex_match_index_list.append(i)
                #else:
                #    pass

            elif doLuhn(str(temp)) is False:
                pass




    else:
        pass
rows =[]


for each in regex_match_index_list:

    changed = data.iloc[each].str.replace(r'(\d\B(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b)', r'(xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx')
   # print("Changed", changed)
    rows.append(changed)
```

When I try to replace the card numbers using str.replace function, I am losing the id column. The id field is empty when I create a new csv after replacing. If remove str.replace the id field is not gone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sot sure, but the `iloc[each]` will return you the entire row. Using `iloc[[each,0]]` might give you the desired output